# Global variables and objects are unable to use in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I create a globla class in springboot and I want to use that class
> content in my thymeleaf templates but when I call these global
> variables in my thymeleaf templates it show unresolved error
> but when i add below line in my thmeleaf template all the errors gone
> from the global variables

```
<!--suppress ThymeleafVariablesResolveInspection -->
```

> common.kt

```
package com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.common

import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Cart
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Category
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Page
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.repository.CategoryRepository
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.repository.PageRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute
import java.security.Principal
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

@ControllerAdvice
class Common {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var pageRepository: PageRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var categoryRepository: CategoryRepository

    @ModelAttribute
    fun sharedData(model: Model, session: HttpSession, principal: Principal?) {
        if (principal != null) {
            model.addAttribute("principal", principal.name)
        }
        val pages: List<Page?>? = pageRepository.findAllByOrderBySortingAsc()
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepository.findAll()
        var cartActive = false
        if (session.getAttribute("cart") != null) {
            val cart: HashMap<Int, Cart> = session.getAttribute("cart") as HashMap<Int, Cart>
            var size = 0
            var total = 0.0
            for (value in cart.values) {
                size += value.quantity
                total += value.quantity * value.price.toDouble()
            }
            model.addAttribute("csize", size)
            model.addAttribute("ctotal", total)
            cartActive = true
        }
        model.addAttribute("cpages", pages)
        model.addAttribute("ccategories", categories)
        model.addAttribute("cartActive", cartActive)
    }
}
```

> cart_partial.html

```
<!--suppress ThymeleafVariablesResolveInspection -->
<div class="bg-dark text-white p-3 mt-3" th:fragment="cart_partial" th:if="${notCartViewPage == null}">
    <div class="cart cartActive" th:if="${cartActive}">
        <p>You have <span th:text="${csize}"></span> items in your cart.</p>
        <p>Total <span th:text="'₹' + ${#numbers.formatDecimal(ctotal, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></span> items in your cart.</p>
        <p>
            <a href="/cart/view" class="btn btn-success">View cart</a>
            <a href="/cart/clear" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Clear cart</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cart cartInactive" th:unless="${cartActive}">
        <p>Your cart is empty.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> what is  the reason that all the errors gone ,but some features are
> not working properly

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *what* is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: want  to use  common..kt  elements  cartActiive,csize,ctotal in cartpartial without any  errror.butt iam not able to use  these elements in my cart  ppaaritaal ,, When I  call ttheese  instanncee  in carttparttial it show an uneexpecteed  error.But whwn i use 
<!--suppress ThymeleafVariablesResolveInspection --> in my  cartpartial all the  red line errroors gone,but tthatt ellemeentts  doesnot work pproperly.

Comment: The suppress message will not fix the issues. It will just... suppress them. From what I can see (and understand) you are using a Thymeleaf Fragment. It is normal for your IDE (I presume IntelliJ?) to show you a warning since the value of the variables used in the fragment is not yet known. Try running the application and see how it behaves.